# asp.net core mvc angular cli error message

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have created a fresh new asp.net core 2.0 angular project.

I am working on mac os x. I have opened a terminal in project subfolder and typed:

```
$ npm install
```

The demo skelton project works fine.

Now i want to work with angular cli.

In my terminal, which is still in project subfolder:

$ npm install -g @angular/cli
$ npm install --save-dev @angular/cli

Now, if i move to components subfolder and if i want to generate an angular component:

```
$ cd ClientApp/app/components/
$ ng g component composant1
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'rxjs/operators'
```

Now, on the same computer, if a create a fresh new angular project (without asp.net core):

```
$ ng new projettemp
```

My ng g component command works fine in this project.

So i suppose this is an asp.net core issue...

** EDIT **

If i type ng version in my project directory, i get the same error.

If i type ng version outside my project directory, i get 1.6.4

Comment: which cli version do you use? `ng version`

Comment: see my edit for this information

Comment: You need generate a new project before generate a component you can follow the steps from, e.g. https://dustinewers.com/angular-cli-with-net-core/

Comment: Asp.net also generate à projet ?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new .net core angular project in Visual Studio and get the same error as you, when trying to create a new component with command `$ ng g component composant1`.

The angular app in the solution is not created by angular cli, so the `.angular.cli.json` file is missing. 
So I tried to create a new angular app as Eliseo recommended in his comment. But same error as with `ng g component` command.

So I update the dependency for the `rxjs` library to `rxjs": "^5.5.6"` in the `packages.json` file and now the `ng g` command  entry gives the error message

> Unable to find any apps in `.angular-cli.json`.

So `angular cli` is working again, but you have to update all dependencies in `package.json` to the newest angular version (in my case it is using an angular version 4) and after that you have to provide a proper `.angular-cli.json` file for your project structure.